# I have to print a triangle of integers of collatz in c

Tags: c

I have to write a program in C which, prints numbers from collatz as a triangle.

Like this:

[image]

I have tried and

This is my output:

[image]

This is my code:

```
    int inputLines, startNum, number;

    printf("Lines: ");
    scanf("%d",& inputLines);

    printf("Start: ");
    scanf("%d",& startNum);

    for(int i = 0; i < inputLines; i++){

         printf("\n");

         for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
             printf("%d ", startNum);

              if(startNum % 2 == 0){

                  startNum = startNum / 2;

              }else{

                startNum = startNum * 3 + 1;
               }
           }
      }
```

Comment: Do not use references to images. Provide all relevant information in the question.

Comment: Also can you work on your question before posting it, you have a lot of typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int inputLines = 4;
    int start = 19;

    for(int i = 0; i < inputLines; i++)
    {
        int n = start;
        for(int j=0; j<i+1; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d ", n);
            n = (n%2)? 3*n+1 : n/2;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```